# Do we need any specific configuration in PC to communicate to android over wifi p2p connection?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-wifi

What I want : Connect Android and Windows Desktop over Wifi and transfer a string from android to windows.[ Assume both are connected to same wifi router ]

What I know : I need to use Socket Communication

What I did : I am going through WiFi p2p documentation at Android Developer Website, It is written at many places that, for communication you need to have p2p supported in devices. My android phone obviously have support.

Question is what about my desktop? How do I know? Any lead is appreciated? Any working example is also invited for same purpose.

Comment: What does "p2p supported in devices" mean?

Comment: p2p is WiFi peer to peer.

Comment: WiFi is always peer to peer, isn't it?

Comment: Couldn't comment. A newbie there me is.

Comment: Oops, I didn't know wifi p2p was a thing, I thought you meant two devices connected to the same network.